# Display currency as different currency type ($10 -> R10)

Tags: delphi, pascal

how does one change the value of the type of currency? I am getting $ for my currency when i need R.

```
procedure TfrmFinal.addSubtractTotal; 
var 
  total: currency; 
begin 
  total := 0; 
  frmDataModule.tblpins.First; 
  while not frmDataModule.tblpins.Eof do 
  begin 
    total := total + 
      frmDataModule.tblpins.FieldByName('qty').AsInteger * 
      frmDataModule.tblpins.FieldByName('price').AsCurrency; 
    frmDataModule.tblpins.Next; 
  end; 
  totalAmmountLabel.Text := total.ToString; 
end;
```

Comment: You don't want to use `toString` in this case. Why not? `toString` is always using global Format Settings which in your case seem to define currency format for $. Instead of `toString` you should be using proper formatting function that is more suitable fur this task. For instance Delphi comes with [System.SysUtils.FormatCurr](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Alexandria/en/System.SysUtils.FormatCurr) that is designed for converting currency into proper string format. ...

Comment: ... Use second version of the said function that has `TFormatSettings` parameter. This will allow you to pass custom Format Settings to the function so you could get desired formatting results and thus desired currency format.

Comment: @SilverWarior that should be posted as an answer, not comments

Comment: I did not post this as an answer because I was writing it at work where I don't have access to computer with Delphi installed.  I believe answer should a bit more detailed like showing an example of how to set format settings to get desired result. Doing this without access to Delphi could lead to making a mistake on my part while writing an answer.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways to solve this.  Unfortunately, I don't have the TCurrencyHelper, but here are a few other options:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
 var Total: Currency;
begin
  Total := 155;
  var FormatSettings := TFormatSettings.Create(7177); //LCID for South Africa, MAY not be necessary if that is the local setting on the machines you are supporting
  button1.Caption := FloatToStrF(Total, ffCurrency, 15,2, FormatSettings);
  button1.Caption := FormatCurr('', Total, FormatSettings);
  button1.Caption := CurrToStr(Total, FormatSettings);
  button1.Caption := CurrToStrF(Total,ffCurrency,2,FormatSettings);
end;
```

All of them are slightly different.  My preference would be CurrToStrF (which then calls FloatToStrF), but that is just out of habit.

Comment: Not completely relevant to the answer, but here are ways to get the LCID:
https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20161007-00/?p=94475
https://www.science.co.il/language/Locale-codes.php